# Facebook Server Site GTM Tracking

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, event-tracking, google-tag-manager-server-side

For my company I am trying to implement server site tracking for meta (facebook). Setup wise everything works fine. My events are collected on my tagging server (via GTM). My only problem right now is that certain parameter values, which I am sending as an array (the form is defined by facebook and we have no problem with the client site tracking), are not in the right format when the server is collecting the request.

Here I give you an example from an add to cart event.

Client site:
[image: client site]

The array with the name contens is giving meta the needed Info about the product and the corresponding quantity.
Now I send this exact same variable over to the Server.
There it looks like this

[image: server site]

So now it is not readable anymore, although I sent the same variable. Does someone have a solution for this? I think it will be something simple I am overlooking.

I tried different test variables for example to send the info as an Object, but then nothing will be send to the server.